# PHP Variable can be read in local enviroment, but not in live

Tags: php

I have a local server running on my laptop that I test my sites on and I have noticed when I uploaded a current site to the live server part broke. I found that the error was caused by a function opperating like this

```
$other=1;
function example(){
$variable =1+$other;
return $variable;
}
```

But that if I put the variable $other into the function it worked fine. Obviously there are different settings on the local server compared to the live, but what makes this happen?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code will give you a syntax error but locally and live.

Comment: Sorry that is a mistake from copying it over. It shouldn't be there

Comment: Sorry, written in haste for pure example purposes. It captures the essence of the problem and what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the parameter in the function:

```
function example($other){
    $variable = 1 + $other;

    return $variable;
}

$other = 1;
example($other);
```

You may want to read about scoping in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should define function like **function test()** not function($)

Comment: Yes your correct. That was my mistake, but in the actual code it is not there. I have updated the question accordingly.